# Accessing code behind functions from WebMethod

Tags: asp.net

I have a code behind page that has several method; one of them is a page method.

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ResetDate(DateTime TheNewDate)
{
    LoadCallHistory(TheNewDate.Date);
}

protected void LoadCallHistory(DateTime TheDate)
{ bunch of stuff }
```

The method LoadCallHistory works fine when the page loads and I can call it from other methods inside the page. However, in the web method part, it gets underlined in red with the error "an object reference is required for the non-static field".

How do you access functions from the page method part of the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot call a non-static method from a static context without having an instance of the class. Either remove `static` from `ResetDate` or make `LoadCallHistory` static.

However, if you remove `static` from `ResetDate` you must have an instance of it to use that method. Another approach is to create an instance of the class inside `ResetDate` and use that instance to call `LoadCallHistory`, something like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ResetDate(DateTime TheNewDate)
{
    var callHistoryHandler = new Pages_CallHistory();
    callHistoryHandler.LoadCallHistory(TheNewDate.Date);
}
```

The error message indicates that `ResetDate` has the keyword `static` and `LoadCallHistory` does not. When using static either both of the methods needs to be static or the called method needs to be `static`, the caller cannot be static if the called method is not.

To quote MSDN on ["Static Classes and Static Class Members"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

> A static class is basically the same
>   as a non-static class, but there is
>   one difference: a static class cannot
>   be instantiated. In other words, you
>   cannot use the new keyword to create a
>   variable of the class type. Because
>   there is no instance variable, you
>   access the members of a static class
>   by using the class name itself.

Comment: +1. In other words, consider changing your LoadCallHistory to be `static` as well.

Comment: It's underlining the part new CallHistoryHandler(); with missing directive. Where does the CallHistoryHandler() object live?

Comment: @frenchie, `CallHistoryHandler` was just an example. What is the class name that `LoadCallHistory()` resides in? You need to create a new instance of that class in order to call `LoadCallHistory()`.

Comment: It's a code behind file; where do I find the instance? (I'm a newbie)

Comment: At the top of your code-behind file you should see something like `public class xxx` what does it say instead of `xxx`?

Comment: Ok, I got it. I just needed to copy-paste Pages_CallHistory from the top line of the code behind file "public partial class Pages_CallHistory : System.Web.UI.Page"

Comment: +1: @frenchie: this answer is very well explained. I think you're very new to C# and probably OOP in general, and as a result, you may not fully realize the difference between `void LocalCallHistory()` and `static void LocalCallHistory()`. Do you understand what the `static` keyword means, and the difference between static and instance methods?

Comment: @frenchie, I've updated my answer, as you see I just replaced `CallHistoryHandler` with `Pages_CallHistory` because in your case `Pages_CallHistory` is the class name and you need to create an instance of this using the keyword `new`. This will let you call methods that "belong" to that class. Meaning the methods that are Not static! Because `static` methods such as `ResetDate` should be possible to call like this: `Pages_CallHistory.ResetDate(DateTime.Now)`. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Juliet: I understand the concepts but it's hard to understand how they're applied in code. Static means lives outside the instance and applies to all instances without being replicable within each instance; from what I understood.

Comment: Can you guys look at my other question. I'm stuck at the moment and I think it's because I'm not doing something right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952156/ajax-with-page-method

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a `static` method, it can only call other `static` methods or new objects.

If your page class is `CallHistory` (educated guess ;)) you will need to do this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void ResetDate(DateTime TheNewDate)
{
    var thisPage = new CallHistory();
    thisPage.LoadCallHistory(TheNewDate.Date);
}
```

Or change `LoadCallHistory` to be `static`.

Comment: So will my thing work? I have a page with a date selector and when the user presses a date, I want the table that's in an updatepanel to be refreshed. For now, I have the page method receive the correct data and now I have the LoadCallHistory function also available. However, I'm not so sure about making the gridview refresh from the page method. I'm working on the databinding of the gridview.

Comment: Can you look at my other question. I'm stuck at the moment and I think it's because I'm not doing something right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952156/ajax-with-page-method