# How to access Code Behind Functions in a WebMethod?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webmethod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing code behind functions from WebMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951248/accessing-code-behind-functions-from-webmethod)

I have following WebMethod, which i'm calling through Json. Its working fine.

```
   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string CheckUserName(string userName)
{
    string returnValue = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        string consString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cn"].ToString();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(consString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UsernameCheck", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName.Trim());
        conn.Open();
        returnValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch
    {
        returnValue = "error";
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

But as we know, we can't access Page control and code behind functions in Static Functions.

But here i have to access a a code behind function in WebMethod. i.e

```
public void test()
  {
   }
```

Please help how can i access "test" function in webmethod. In test function i have used two repeater control and datatable.

Thank You.

Comment: You are aware that we can't access page controls in web method. Do you thing is it possible via another method?

Comment: there may be a solution for this problem, I'm trying to do this.

Comment: @ADSinghKamboj, you did not specify what you want to achieve, only what you want to do (even if you know it is not possible). If you want recomendation - say what you trying to do, in addition to how you trying to do that.

Comment: @OzgurDogus, I want to bind 5 repeater cntrols, on click of a LinkButton, But i don't like when Page get load for this...

Answer (score 0):

I understood you. But what you trying to do is not possible that way.

The webmethod is returned to a script inside the page, I guess, so you are not able to call another instance method from page.

What you may try is to do a postback to the same page after the result, and call the `test()` method again. Then you will be able to refresh your repeaters and datatable.

Another solution is to return the repeater as html by the webmethod.